# Count future occurrences of a value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have two tables. One table has distinct id. I will call it `distinct`

```
id  date
---------------
a   2017-01-01
b   2016-01-01
c   2017-01-01
```

The other table is a log of all occurrences of an id. I will call it `log`

```
id    date
-----------------
a     2017-01-01
a     2016-01-01
b     2017-01-01
c     2017-01-01
b     2016-01-01
b     2015-01-01
```

The table I want is the count of all ids on and after their date listed in `distinct`. In this toy example the result would be the following:

```
id  count
-----------
a     1    -- on or after 2017-01-01
b     2    -- on or after 2016-01-01
c     1    -- on or after 2017-01-01
```

Comment: What have you tried? You just need to join on id _and_ date, but the join on date would not be `=`, it'd be `>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a `join` and `group by`:

```
select d.id, count(l.id)
from distinct d left join
     log l
     on l.id = d.id and l.date >= d.date
group by d.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :-

```
select d.id, count(*) as cnt
from distinct d 
join log l 
on d.id = l.id
where l.date >= d .date
group by d.id
```